Aggregated Add-in organization
I've got a collection of add-ins (separate xslm), which I would like to organize in one central xlam (add-in). So the the issue is that I don't have any other organizational mechanism apart from the modules, classes and forms. Since there are too much of them any further developement or bug-fixes, will be a pain, if I copy them to the central file.
My main idea would be to use VBE > References and to reference the needed files (xslm / xlam / or other).
In this manner I'll be able to hold my programs in separate logical parts, which will be much easier for further work with.

The main questions is, would I'll be able to change the separate programs, without to change anything in the central add-in and use it futher as-is with the updated logic ?
Is there another organizational logic, which I could use ?
Thank you in advance
My main idea would be to use VBE > References and to reference the needed files (xslm / xlam / or other).

If your add-ins share related functionality it seems like there would be some efficiency in combining them into a single file (you can share common methods for example).  If they're totally unrelated then maybe they really belong as separate files?

@TimWilliams, thank you. Unfortunately, they are unrelated ...
